Behavior of Perturbed Functions with uniform noise
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and let $\xi(x)$ be a uniformly distributed random variable with variance $\sigma^2 > 0$, independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Define $\phi(x) = f(x) + \xi(x)$. Show that for every sequence $\{x^k\}, \{y^k\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x^k\ne y^k$ for all $k$, we have:
$$P\left(\limsup_{k \to \infty} |\phi(x^k) - \phi(y^k)| = 0\right) = 0.$$

By the converse of Borel-Cantelli for independent events, it suffices to show (for some $\varepsilon > 0$) that $$\inf_{x\neq y}\mathbb{P}[|\phi(x)-\phi(y)| \geq \varepsilon] > 0$$
For any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $$\mathbb{P}[|\phi(x) - \phi(y)|\geq  \varepsilon] = \mathbb{P}[\phi(x)-\phi(y) \notin (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}[\xi(x)-\xi(y) \notin (f(y) - f(x) - \varepsilon, f(y) - f(x) + \varepsilon)]$$
So it suffices to show anti-concentration of $\xi(x) - \xi(y)$, that is to say that the chance of this variable landing in any sufficiently small interval is at most $\rho < 1$. By independence $\xi(x)-\xi(y)$ has variance $2\sigma^2$ (and in particular is non-constant). So, in any case, we've reduced the problem to showing that given any r.v. $X$ which isn't constant, there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that:
$$ \sup_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{P}[|X-t| < \varepsilon] < 1$$
(This supremum here and the $\varepsilon$ depend on the distribution of $X$, but since $\xi(x)-\xi(y)$ is i.i.d. for pairs $x \neq y$, this is not a problem for us.) If $X$ is not constant, then there are at least two distinct $t_1, t_2$ such that $\mathbb{P}[|X-t_i| < \varepsilon]> 0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. Taking $\varepsilon = |t_2 - t_1|/10$ gives you the desired bound.
(It is worth emphasizing that this proof works even if the distribution of $\xi$ has heavy tails and no variance; you just need non-constant.)
